# What's the most efficient way to calculate the Wiger quasiprobability distribution?

Tags: algorithms, efficiency

I want to calculate the [Wigner quasiprobability distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_quasi-probability_distribution) of a particular wavefunction. The definition suggests a few straightforward ways of calculating it, but I was wondering if there's something more efficient than the naive approaches of either directly evaluating the integral or taking the fft of the autocorrelation.

Comment: I have found the integral to be one of the more annoying ones because the integrand is pretty oscillatory. Is this paper helpful? http://mechatronics.ece.usu.edu/foc/FRFT/references/00902121Fast%20computation%20of%20the%20ambiguity%20function%20and%20the%20Wigner.pdf

Comment: @AlexE: The paper itself isn't especially helpful, but some of the articles it cites are. In any case, the faster algorithms appear complicated enough that I think I'll start with the naive ones, if only to save on coding time.

Comment: Great. Please let us know if you find a good method or good literature. In how many dimensions is your signal/wavefunction defined?

Comment: @AlexE: In this case it's just one. Given the dimensionality of the wigner functions of high-dimensionality wavefunctions, I suspect that most people working on non-1D problems would project to 1D before calculating the Wigner distribution.

Comment: That's what I had done, too. It's very common also in classical dynamics, compare mathworld.wolfram.com/SurfaceofSection.html
Also consider other phase space distributions, such as Husimi's one: http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.55.645